# Tesseract OCR only detect user-words

Tags: command-line, tesseract

I've been at this for a bit but I can't seem to restrict Tesseract to only output words from the "user-words" dictionary I built. I don't want anything else, just basic matching against those words.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try Tesseract's [*bazaar*](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc#config-files-and-augmenting-with-user-data) configuration.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work :/ do mind providing a bit more information?

Comment: @Hexiro The feature may no longer work in latest versions of Tesseract.