# Tesseract OCR user patterns

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Is there any way to get Tesseract to match only user-specified words or patterns?  The [manual](https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/git/doc/tesseract.1.html) claims it is possible, yet I cannot find a single documented instance on the internet of somebody getting this working.

Here are many examples of people asking for help because it does not work, and none have a proven resolution.

[stackoverflow.com/questions/33429143/tesseract-user-pattern-is-not-applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429143/tesseract-user-pattern-is-not-applied)

[stackoverflow.com/questions/31874393/tesseract-ocr-force-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874393/tesseract-ocr-force-pattern)

[stackoverflow.com/questions/26856349/provide-pattern-for-tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856349/provide-pattern-for-tesseract)

[stackoverflow.com/questions/22432194/tesseract-ocr-only-detect-user-words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432194/tesseract-ocr-only-detect-user-words)

[stackoverflow.com/questions/17209919/tesseract-user-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209919/tesseract-user-patterns)

[groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/S9CIK3jOMWw](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/S9CIK3jOMWw)

[groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/5vFqVcJmHnM](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/5vFqVcJmHnM)

So can we conclude that this feature simply does not work? Is there an official statement to this effect?

Comment: A lot of the linked Tesseract documents appear to have moved. [Here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc) is a link to a manual on github.

Comment: Year later, still appears to be the case.

Comment: The link to the manual is dead

Comment: Repo admins say that user-patterns broke somewhere around v3.02. LSTM v4.0 probably has broken user-patterns as well as char-whitelisting https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/960

Answer (score 7):

There is now an example on the Tesseract doc site at https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/APIExample-user_patterns.html [Thanks @Ravi for the new link]

That test example does work for me in the oem=1 / LSTM mode of Tesseract 4.x.

I can't, however, get it to work for any other examples, or in any other modes.

I have seen no official statement and at the time of writing it does indeed seem that the feature is non-functional.

Comment: Why the downvote? The fact that this is all there is after 3 years is not my fault. Must I rather delete the answer?

Comment: Still not able to get this to work using the windows binaries.